# Joomla home looses sef alias for component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

I am developing a component for joomla 1.7/2.5 with a few modules that generate sef links to the component with different views.
Everything is shiny and fine, except for the home page of the site so http: //localhost/en/

When I'm on the home page all my component links change to http: //localhost/en/**component/componentname**/category/2032 wheres if I use this link: http: //localhost/en/whateverhere the same links are like they should be http: //localhost/en/**component_menu_alias**/category/2032

no content and no menu has the alias "whateverhere" so I'm confused as to how joomla knows the right alias when it's on whateverhere and not when it's on the home http: //localhost/en/

Any ideas as of what is going wrong here?

P.S.: the page is multy lingual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am soon to face that challenge myself, and have [Supporting SEF URLs in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) bookmarked.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: the thing is that I have followed this tutorial to create the router for my component. But unlike it says in the tutorial http://www.example.com/[menualias]/[view]/[slug] this will be true only for a non-multilingual page or when you already are under any menu alias but not if you are http://www.example.com/[lang_sef]/

Comment: I'm afraid it's been 25 years since I've done a multilingual site, and it wasn't Joomla.  All i can suggest is to look into JoomFish - that seems to be the de-facto multilingual component for Joomla - Good Luck.